# VS stuck at `Loading` when starting debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-designer

This happened After updating Visual Studio to `16.2.0`:

`Start Debugging` > `Building started` > `Building succeeded` > `App launches [Suspended]`

[image] >

`Loading... [Stuck/VS instance blocked]`

[image]

Other projects run just fine, and so does running without a debugger.

What's causing that and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

This turned out to be a problem with the designer (or related to it). Right now, if i open the project it gets stuck at loading designer. I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504513/visual-studio-hangs-after-changes-in-a-xaml-file) and it had a workaround in the accepted answer which was to remove the project`.sln` file and use the `.csproj` file instead. This also fixed getting stuck while starting debug.

<s>I tried looking up this issue with no luck finding an answer.</s>

Comment: @mjwills Well, it's not reproducible. As i mentioned, It only happens for this particular single project.

Comment: So it is **reproducible** - with that one project. So now you should copy that project, and try and make it **minimal** (i.e. remove as much as possible to the point where it is as small as possible, but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703475/visual-studio-freezing-crashing-while-loading-solution) fixed the problem by simply deleting the `.vs` folder in the project folder.